# Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking and the _link() method

Tags: google-analytics

I have read the documentation for the Traditional Syntax here: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#multipleDomains

Unfortunately I think there's some errors in the example code in the section titled "Tracking Between a Domain and a Sub-Directory on Another Domain".  The sample of that section starts by saying the main domain is "www.example.com" and the blog domain is "www.blog-hosting-service.com".  But then in the code examples they start using "www.example-petstore.com" which lowers my confidence that the code that follows is 100% accurate.

Here's what I have going on.  Site A is the "main site" and both site A and Site B are correctly set up to handle cross domain tracking with the Traditional Syntax.

I know that forms and links need to use the _linkByPost() and  _link() methods respectively. 
But I'm unclear on if I need to use the _link() method when going from Site B back to Site A.
I've done several searches on the web and can't seem to find a clear consensus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you have to use `_link()` method on both sites in links between them. To make it more clear, refer to this conversion university guide: http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/v5/domains_subdomainsv22_ad1/ (from p.6).

Comment: Except that these guide is also outdated. Please don't use `_setDomainName('none')`, it's not needed anymore.

Comment: The online application I'm working on is old, and it uses the "Traditional Syntax" everywhere. Because of its age, this is probably why I'm getting so many conflicting instructions from Google, especially on what's supposed to be in _setDomainName()... "none" or "mysite.com" or ".mysite.com".

Comment: @Nikolay, can you give me the URL to where this video is linked from?  Meaning, is the a page that has lots of these videos out there? Thanks!

Comment: @Ben, sure, it's a google conversion university lessons: http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/iq.html?

Comment: Here's another related question I have, if you happen to know... http://stackoverflow.com/q/9517284/261375