# Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking: Asynchronous on one site... Traditional on the other

Tags: google-analytics

Will Cross Domain Tracking work between site-a.com and site-b.com, if for Example, site-a.com uses Asynchronous tracking code, but site-b.com uses the older "Traditional Syntax"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't matter how the data gets to GA's servers, as long as it gets there.  If site-b.com and site-a.com are setup correctly, the fact that its a cross-domain configuration will not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you know where it says this in any Google documentation.  I've searched and searched but couldn't find it.

Comment: No I doubt that you will find it documented anywhere. My answer is from experience.  There are not 2 public GA API's.  There is one, with two different methods of pushing data: synchronously or asynchronously.  You can test this by putting async code on some pages of site-a.com and the older code one other pages of the same site.  It will work just fine that way, too.